# Launch an activity at end of a phone call on Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to launch an activity at the end of a phone call.
Could not find any reference to that. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but I would assume you could have some service running(always on in background), that utilizes the [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html). You could then listen for `LISTEN_CALL_STATE` which says it "Listen for changes to the device call state". I would assume this would fire when a call starts, stops, etc. You could then launch your activity from the service when you receive a message that a call ended.

Note you would probably have to track the states, and no when you are in `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` and go to `CALL_STATE_IDLE` that the call ended.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use a service.
You could register a Receiver in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file like that:

```
<receiver android:name=".callerID.IncomingCallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="0">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In you Java class check the phone state and launch your desired activity - DON'T forget to launch it with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.