# Adding a "View" to the recieving/placing call window on android

Tags: android, textview, phone-call, invisible

I am looking for some help, not being spoon feed source code (which from some of the threads I have read on this forum wouldn't happen anyway).  I am really just wanting to know if what I have conjured up in my head is even possible or not, and if it is if I could get pointed in the right direction.  So, I am looking to add a "view", doesn't really matter what type the concept would be the same for all of them, to appear when receiving or placing a phone call.  You know the one that has the little droid waving at you or a photo, etc.  The only thing is that I would only want like the top 30px to be this "view".

For instance, you receive a phone call and at the top of your screen on top of the receiving call window is a TextView with a note about this person (i.e. - he stinks).

The only thing I have been able to come up with so far is that I would have to bring up a layout that was either invisible or gone, but have yet to figure it out as of yet.

Am I barking up the right tree or do I need to find a different tree to sniff.  Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know the answer to this, but if it were possible then presumably you would have to have your own custom Activity launch in response to an incoming phone call event. This Activity of your own would replace the standard system phone application. So I did a search on here and the most vaguely related previous questions I could find within a short time are these:

[Is it possible to write a new "phone" activity, and if yes then how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865414/is-it-possible-to-write-a-new-phone-activity-and-if-yes-then-how)

[Launch an activity at end of a phone call on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776588/launch-an-activity-at-end-of-a-phone-call-on-android)

Answers on those seem to suggest the phone would need to be rooted before you could replace the standard phone app for receiving calls.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I don't necessarily want to replace the phone activity, but instead place a textview, about the size of what an ad banner would be, on top of the phone activity.  So, basically is there a way to place for example a LinearLayout which is invisible with a textview that IS visible and the use can still touch the buttons on the phone activity?